# Matrix 3d() transform property?

Tags: css, matrix

I want know how to use the matrix 3d() property of a 4X4 matrix (I know how to use one for a 3x3 matrix)...

```
[m11 m12 m13 m14]
[m21 m22 m23 m24]
[m31 m32 m33 m34]
[m41 m42 m43 m44]
```

what does m13, m23, m31, m32 do?

I know for all others.

Comment: hello please check it link http://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/                                           http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp

Comment: hmmm, looks like this is much more that i am thinking ( really great Maths).... thankx for help... can you tell me any suggestions so that i can learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this

```
[1 0 0 dx]
[0 1 0 dy]
[0 0 1 dz]
[0 0 0 1 ]
```

it will move object by (dx, dy, dz) vector

m11 equals m[0][0]

m21 equals m[2][1]